# How can I show the child category and not it's parent - but other times show it's parent?

Tags: categories

I have a categories field on an entry that can have one or many children. I am able to output everything - but would like to restrict the field a bit more.

If a child has been selected, I do not want to show the parent. In my example, I only want to show "child".

It is possible, that I might only choose "parent" and I only want that to show. Or, is there a different way I should go about doing this? Thank you for any suggestions!

[image]

I've tried something like this:

```
{% for service in entry.servies %}
   {% set subCategories = craft.categories.descendantOf(service) %}

   {% if subCategories|length %}
       ...
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But that will show the child category if it's selected or not. I would only like to show the "Child" category if it was actually selected. Otherwise, show the "parent" category.

**UPDATE/SOLUTION**

First, I want to thank Robin for your help. I tried different variations and was unsuccessful. I ended up taking my existing category and making it a structure. This gave me the flexibility that I needed.

Comment: I'm not sure if that works so it might be totally wrong (I can't test it now) but have you tried to order your entries by `level` and select the first? That way it might be possible to select only the deepest entry (child). Btw: if this is for Craft 3 keep in mind looping through queries is deprecated

Comment: Yes it's Craft 3. I have a category called "Service Types". 

On my entry, I have a category field called "Services". I'm trying to only show the category that was selected. I would like to not show the parent if the child was selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a category, try creating each service within a structure. Then use an `entries` field to establish the relationship within the CP.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the sort order in your `CategoryQuery`

```
{% set child = entry.getFieldValue('servies').orderBy('level DESC').one() %}
```

returns the category of the deepest level -> the child. If no child is selected you'll receive the parent

Comment: Hey Robin - thank you so much! I'm getting the child now like I'd like, but adding the `one()` will (obviously) only get me a single category. My entry could belong to several categories - some may have a child, some may not.

Comment: That's why I never understood Pixel and Tonic decision to make Category fields the way they are. The most easiest solution would be to create a custom field type.. Copy this https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/fields/Entries.php and change the word `Entry` to `Category` and you are done after you registered your new field type. Only Category fields fill the gaps https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/fields/Categories.php#L91

Answer (score 1):

You can get the highest level of categories in your field and then filter your field only on that level.

```
{% set level = 0 %}
{% for productCategory in block.productCategories.all %}
    {% set level = productCategory.level > level ? productCategory.level : level %}
{% endfor %}

{% for productCategory in block.productCategories.level(level).all %}
    Do somestuff
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through the selected categories, collect their ancestors and exclude them from the final entry query.

This syntax is wrong but something like:

```
{% set services = entry.services %}
{% set ancestors = [] %}

{% for service in services %}
  {% set ancestors = ancestors|merge(service.getAncestors()) %}
{% endfor %}

{% set mostSpecificServiceCategories = craft.categories(services).without(ancestors) %}

{% set entries = craft.entries.services(mostSpecificServiceCategories) %}
```